# How to use Write[stream, expression] without automatic addition of next line character

Tags: string-manipulation, files-and-directories

I am writing a C code for solving a big set of differential equations. I am trying to use Mathematica to export some of the long expressions to C. I would like to know how I could use Write[stream, expression] without adding a newline character. An example of what I exactly want is as follows.

```
t=0;    
str=OpenWrite["file path"];
   WriteString[str, "A[" ]; Write[str,t ]; WriteString[str, "] = 0;"];
```

I want this to be printed into the file as

```
A[0] = 0;
```

instead of

```
A[0
] = 0;
```

Also, the parameter t cannot be supplied manually. "t" is set before passing it as an argument to Write or some other similar function.If this cannot work, is there any other way of doing this ?
. 
Thanks

Comment: `WriteString[str,Tostring[0]]` is one way

Comment: that said, its cleaner i think to build up the whole thing and use `Export`, eg `code = {"A[" <> ToString[0] <> "]=0;", "A[" <> ToString[1] <> "]=1;"};
Export["file.c", code, "Lines"];`

Comment: George, thank you very much. Your "ToString" technique worked perfectly !....This is all I needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two differences between `Write` and `WriteString`:

1. `Write` adds a newline after all expressions, `WriteString` does not.
2. `Write` uses the `FormatType` of the output stream (default `InputForm`), `WriteString` uses `OutputForm`.

`WriteString` does *not* require its argument to be a string.  Therefore, the simplest fix is to just change the second `Write` to `WriteString`.

```
WriteString[str, "A["]; WriteString[str, 0]; WriteString[str, "] = 0;"]

(* A[0] = 0;          -- no trailing newline *)
```

Alternatively, we could write out all the expressions with a single call to `WriteString`:

```
WriteString[str, "A[", 0, "] = 0;"]

(* A[0] = 0;          -- no trailing newline *)
```

If we want a newline after the semicolon, we can add an explicit newline:

```
WriteString[str, "A[", 0, "] = 0;\n"]

(* A[0] = 0;          -- with trailing newline *)
```

or add an extra write:

```
WriteString[str, "A[", 0, "] = 0;"]
Write[str]

(* A[0] = 0;          -- with trailing newline *)
```

If we open the file using `FormatType -> OutputForm`, then we can use a single `Write` to put the statement on a line of its own:

```
str = OpenWrite["zot", FormatType -> OutputForm];
Write[str, "A[", 0, "] = 0;"]
Close[str];
FilePrint["zot"]
DeleteFile["zot"]

(* A[0] = 0;          -- with trailing newline *)
```

---

**Aside: Symbolic C**

If you are going to be doing a lot of C code generation, you might want to look at [Symbolic C](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/SymbolicC/tutorial/Overview.html).  It allows high-level expression of intent and takes away all the nasty string quoting and concatenation.

```
Needs["SymbolicC`"]

CStatement[CAssign[CArray["A", 0], 123]] // ToCCodeString

(* A[0] = 123; *)

CFunction[int, myfunction, {{int, i}}
, CReturn[COperator[Times, {i, 10}]]
] // ToCCodeString

(* 
     int myfunction(int i)
     {
     return i * 10;
     }
*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I actually forgot to mention that the numbers inside Write or the parameter t in the update post above cannot be supplied manually.

Comment: Since both `Write` and `WriteString` evaluate their arguments, it does not matter whether a value is a constant, variable or arbitrary expression.